# Cloak room to leave luggage at Toronto

Tags: luggage, toronto

I want to leave my luggage somewhere in Toronto on 10th August night and pick it up before 4pm, 11th August to catch my flight. Where can I leave and what are the charges?

Comment: Do you mean at the airport only, or anywhere in town as well?